# How the Google implement multiple user edit in Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

How can the Google doc know there is a user is editing the same document at the same time? How can it sync the docs? Is there true that the Google keep pulling the server, and checking what is the other guy is doing in the same document, and use the js to render the result? Any ideas on that? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google is using HTTP Long-polling to create an open connection to their servers from the browser. As soon as they get an update from someone, they push that change to everyone that has an open connection. Then use Javascript to fill that to the current view.

Comment: and what algorithm is used to synchronize the possibly conflicting edits (and selection, etc.)? (FIFO?)

Comment: @naxa: Operational Transformation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). It's not really one algorithm but many, and I really urge you to use a library instead of trying to implement it yourself. The hottest framework that implements OT right now is Meteor.js. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

yes. its true. depending on your browser version it does continous requests (you can even watch them with applications like httpfox or something) or use a socket stream